# How to open multiple projects in WebStorm from command line?

Tags: ide, webstorm

I understand that I can open a project in WebStorm from terminal using its shell tools.

At the moment, WebStorm open the current working directory with the command `webstorm .`

However, if I navigate to a different project (say project2) in my terminal and run the same command `webstorm .` again. I expect WebStorm to open my project2 in a new window, but for some reason this doesn't happen.

Please let me know if there is a setting which should be enabled to use this feature.

All other editors (VS Code, Atom, Sublime) support this, I'm hoping that WebStorm would also have a similar feature.

Comment: Are you using a Mac?

Comment: Yes. I am using terminal on Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a little clunky because it only works on a Mac, but I came up with a work around for this issue.
1. Paste this into your `.bash_profile`:

```
# Open WebStorm project
ws(){
  for var in "$@"
    do
    open -a /Applications/WebStorm.app "$var"
  done
}
```

2. To use, open your terminal (make sure it's a new terminal session so it reflects the `.bash_profile` changes) and run:

```
$ ws /some/project/directory
```

or to open multiple projets at the same time:

```
$ ws /some/project/directory /some/other/project/directory
```

This will focus the window of the project being opened. Also, if the project is already opened, it will only focus the project's window rather than opening a new session.

Comment: Great! Webstorm's own shell tool doesn't do this but opening Webstorm app from terminal works as expected. Many thanks!